# Steam hammer.exe Load custom textures for other players?

Tags: steam, hammer

I sometimes make maps with custom textures, models, materials, sounds, etc. and I showed one of my map creations to my friend, and the custom textures were pink-and-black. It was intended to be a 'display-case' map with custom sprays & sounds upon clicking a button, but he just saw black and pink textures. Is there a way to make it built-in to the map and have it auto-download? I had the textures in its own folder, like "cars/materials/texture1.vtf"; it wasn't in the actual materials folder of my steam, it was just in its own folder. If I place the textures in the Steam materials/models/etc folder, will it automatically download it for other users?

**ON SINGLEPLAYER/LAN, BUT KNOWLEDGE FOR MULTIPLAYER WILL BE NICE FOR FUTURE REFERENCE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and no its not always the best idea.

If you store materials models and sounds, the person will be downloading 1 file which is much simpler but it bloats the map file to incredible sizes. Some custom mappers have noted going with a resource downloader when their maps reached 500+ megabytes in size which causes problems when downloading a single file on an unstable connection.

If your going to do this anyway then use this link. [Valve Software Wiki Pakrat info](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Pakrat)

This video here is from a Guy I've learned some decent stuff in the past. [3kliksphilip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e54-g9laS-M)

First step shows simple uploading to the workshop while step 2 uses pakrat to add the materials. You can do step 2 without step 1 but this video has merit because everything pretty much goes on the workshop these days.

Now the better way is sending all the files separately. The advantage to this is if you change the map but not any textures, they only need to redownload the map and not the textures. This is considered advanced and I can't find a way to explain it simply.

Comment: Thank you. c: So I should upload it to the workshop?

Comment: Yea, steams workshop is a cloud file share in a simple sense which allows people to just go to the page for your map and click download. it also keeps it up to date so any future revisions will be auto updated if they are using it.

Comment: One last thing to clarify; If I use custom textures in the map, for example if I use a texture for a 'credits' thing hidden in the map that says something like 'map name; created by me', and that texture is in cstrike/models/mytextures/credits.vtf, it will download automatically when I upload JUST the map to the workshop?

Comment: for something like that id recommend adding to the map through pakrat. this way its sort of a signature that you made it and nobody else

Comment: Alright, but for just custom textures in general, it would be just uploading the map and it would automatically download custom textures from the map if any are detected, right?